# How do I access EJB bean when inside a custom Converter

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, converters

This `converter` is called from my JSF. I already register it inside `faces-config.xml`

```
public class ProjectConverter implements Converter{

    @EJB
    DocumentSBean sBean;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{logging}")
    private Logging log;    

    public ProjectConverter(){
    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) 
    {
        if(value.trim().equals("")){
            return null;
        }
        return sBean.getProjectById(value);

    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) 
    {
        if(value == null){
            return null;
        }
        return String.valueOf(((Project) value).getId());
    }
}
```

I ran into `java.lang.NullPointerException`, when I am in `getAsObject()`, the primary reason is because my Session Bean `sBean` is null. I dont know how to fix this, I need to access to my Session bean so that I can query from my database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) said, injection only works in managed beans. You can however declare your converter as a managed bean in your faces-config

```
<managed-bean>
   <managed-bean-name>myConverter</managed-bean-name>
   <managed-bean-class>com.example.MyConverter</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

And later reference it in a jsf component with an el expression:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.value}" converter="#{myConverter}" />
```

Comment: uhmmm, that is interesting, I will try that. Thank you much :D +1

Comment: did it work to your experience? I haven't tried it (no EJB here), however this should in *theory* indeed work, but but I've seen resources confirming that this didn't work. Or it must be dependent on the way how you set the converter in the view.

Comment: @BalusC: Referring to your comment "it must be dependent on the way how you set the converter in the view". I just tried it with `h:selectOneMenu` and it worked if I use the `converter` attribute as described in the answer above but not if I use `<f:converter converterId="...">`. Though the converter is annotated with `@FacesConverter` as well.

Comment: Since JSF 2.3 you can just annotate the converter with  @FacesConverter(managed = true)